# Duplicates in bash history

Tags: bash, command-history

I have the following in my `~/.bashrc`

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
```

However my history contains many duplicates e.g. I have 5 entries for `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

I am running `Raspbian` `Jessie` and principally access via `ssh`.

PS I just entered `sudo apt-get upgrade` while writing this and now only have a single entry.
Any idea why, and how I can prevent it?

Comment: From the way you phrased your question, it is unclear if the duplicates were recorded before of after adding `HISTCONTROL` setting.

Comment: @techraf I have had this setting for some years (migrated from OS X), this is not a new problem. I was just finding it annoying when reviewing my history.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No need of erasedups as you are already giving ignoreboth.

Ignoreboth will take care of duplicates and white space commands.

Just try only ignoreboth or erase dups.

```
"HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth"
```

Use only this and reload bash .
Thank you.

Comment: From what I understand reading the bash man page, "ignoredups" and "erasedups" are slightly different. "ignoredups" causes a line matching the previous entry not to be saved. "erasedups" causes all previous matching history entries to be erased (not just the previous one).

Comment: I changed to `HISTCONTROL=ignorespace:erasedups` which seems to work and do what I want i.e. put latest entries last and replace older entries.

Comment: No. A `erasedups` will scan the whole history and remove all found dups. The `ignoredups` will ignore **only** the last dup. They are not equivalent. Only if the list of commands is clean of dups both will produce similar results. But `erasedups` imply more work as the whole list will be scanned.

Answer (score 1):

To uniquely record every new command is tricky. First you need to add to
`~/.profile` or similar:

```
HISTCONTROL=erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

Then you need to add to `~/.bash_logout`:

```
history -a
history -w
```

Comment: No. Every new command is recorded in **memory** (as configured), `history` command will list such recorded commands list. To send that list of commands to a file you need `history -w`. The `erasedups` acts on the memory list, not on the file list.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two** lists of commands:

- In memory.
- In file.

The setting for HISTCONTROL acts over the memory list. That list could be seen by the command  `history` without options. If you type a command it will be appended to the list. If the command to add is equal to the last command in the list and the option `ignoredups` is set, or the option `erasedups` is set, the command will be discarded. In this case, both options have some similarity.
If the option `erasedups` is set, all previous appearances of the command will be removed from the memory list (but not from file). This removal will **only** happen for a new repeated command. That is: repeated commands will stay until a new command is to be appended to the list.

To write the memory list to file there is the command `history -w` (which will replace the whole file by a new copy). The list in file will not be updated until it is written. Or appended with `history -a` (which will append only new lines that have not been appended before and may leave older repeated commands in the file). When bash exit, the option `histappend` will choose between replacing or appending to the file. Apending may leave repeated commands intact.

One way to clean the file list (keeping the last appearance of a command) is:

```
$ history | sort -urk2 | sort -n | sed 's/^ \+[0-9]\+ \+//'  >~/.bash_history
```

One way to append each command to file is to use the prompt command bash variable to execute a `history -w` on each new command line:

```
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
```

To make this automatic, all the following commands should be added to `~/.bashrc` (usually in linux) or `~/.profile` (usually in mac):

```
HISTFILE=${HISTFILE:-~/.bash_history}
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth:erasedups
PROMPT_COMMAND='history -w'
nl "$HISTFILE"|sort -k2 -k 1,1nr|uniq -f1|sort -n|cut -f2- >"${HISTFILE}.temp" && mv "$HISTFILE"{.temp,}
history -c; history -r
```